# What is the meaning of this error in django-framework

Tags: python, django

> [03/Jul/2021 12:37:09] "GET /Calculatorapp HTTP/1.1" 200 2941
> [03/Jul/2021 12:37:09] "GET /static/logo.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1783

Answer (score 0):

`404` means page not found

you do not have a route for `/static/logo.jpg` ... its probably not the end of the world but some image is probably not showing

Answer (score 0):

it means that the `image` with `src="/static/logo.jpg"` was not found.
basically `404` status code means `NOT FOUND`.